# Insert value to function in python file using Chaquopy in Android Studio

Tags: python, android-studio, chaquopy

I am trying to insert 'Hello World' to def m(input) in python file. But it is not working how can I solve that?

main.py

```
def m(input):
    return input
```

MainActivity.java

```
if(!Python.isStarted())
    Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(this));

Python py = Python.getInstance();
PyObject pyf = py.getModule("main");
PyObject obj = pyf.callAttr("m('Hello World')");
text.setText(obj.toString());
```

This is the error I got

```
com.chaquo.python.PyException: AttributeError: module 'main' has no attribute 'm('Hello World')'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments to `callAttr` should be passed separately, not as a single Python expression. For example:

```
pyf.callAttr("m", "Hello world");
```

For more information, see the [`callAttr` documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/java/com/chaquo/python/PyObject.html#callAttr(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) and the [examples](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/java.html).